# Schlag's proof of the bigPicard theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I am trying to understand the proof of Picard's big theorem which is theorem $4.20$ in Wilhelm Schlag's book *A course in complex analysis and Riemann surfaces*.

The theorem is stated as follows

> If $f$ has an isolated essential singularity at $z_0$, then in any small neighborhood of $z_0$ the funtion $f$ attains every complex value infinitely many ofther with one possible exception.

Schlag claims this is an application of Montel's normality test which says

> Any family of functions $\mathcal{F}$ in $\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$ which omits two distinct values in $\mathbb{C}$ is a normal family.

Schlag proves the big Picard theorem in a few lines as follows:

> Let $z_0=0$ and define $f_n(z) = f(2^{-n}z)$ for an integer $n\geq 1$. We take $n$ so large that $f_n$ is analytic on $0<\lvert z\rvert < 2$. Then $f_{n_k}(z)\rightarrow F(z)$ uniformly on $1/2\leq \lvert z\rvert \leq 1$ where either $F$ is analytic of $F\equiv\infty$. In the former case, we infer from the maximum principle that $f$ is bounded near $z=0$, which is therefore removable. In the latter case, $z=0$ is a pole.

I understand the steps that are taken in the proof but I am confused as to how it proves the statement. I guess he uses some sort of contraposition and assumes that $f$ omits two values in a neighborhood of $z_0$. But I am not sure how that shows $f$ hits every complex value infinitely often with one exception (which can be reached finitely many times).

Comment: the crucial step is that $f_n$ forms a normal family when it omits two values; (which is actually quite non-trivial and is really equivalent to Picard - follows from Bloch/Schotkky theorems without using modular stuff); note that this is true starting from any $n$ so the values must be omitted in every small neighborhood of the singularity, which is exactly contrapositive with values taken infinitely many times

Comment: So the proof starts by supposing the function $f$ attains two values only finitely many times? If so, when Schlag takes his $n$ large, shouldn't he also take it large enough such that the $f_n$ actually omit these two values?

Comment: That is implicitly assumed in the proof and shouldn't have to be mentioned at the math level where Picard theorem lives

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments! I understand now what the author means. I do disagree with your final statement however, it is the authors sloppiness which led me to asking this question, so adhering to a certain level of rigour is always important, at any math level, in my opinion.

Comment: @happy to be of help - I haven't read the Schlag book so not sure how the author treats results, notations, proofs in general so it may be that the book is annoying in places (as noted this approach to Picard is a well known classic one, as an alternative to the modular approach which is less organic imho)

Answer (score 1):

He is proving that a function holomorphic in a annulus $\{z:0<|z|<R\}$ which omits
two values has either a removable singularity or a pole at $z=0$, and certainly
**does not** have an essential singualarity there.